# Dynamic segment in ember data adapter

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm making an app that retrieves data of an API which is not in my control. I have the following scenario:

The path for retrieving the posts is `/api/posts`. So I configured my ApplicationAdapter as follows:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    namespace: 'api'
});
```

The url for retrieving comments is '/api/posts/1/comments'. You can see that the url is prefixed by the path for retrieving a single `post` followed by the default path `/comments`.

Ember data defaults to `/api/comments`. But I want to configure an adapter for my `Comment`-model so it makes the correct url: `/api/posts/:post_id/comments` with `:post_id` replaced with the id of the current post. How do I do that?

Comment: Do you want to do `/api/posts/1/comments` just when you do `post.get('comments')` but when using `store.find('comments')`, the url will be `/api/comments`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your post json to include the hasMany as links (this could be done clientside), when it builds up the url it will prepend the url of the post, giving you `post/1/comments`

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
   comments: DS.hasMany('comment', {async:true})
});

{
  post:{
    id: 1,
    links: {
      comments: 'comments'
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a dinky example with `colors` and `items`

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/68/edit

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to pass parameters to the linked url? Like this: `post.get('comment',{ from: '2014-01-01', to: '2014-01-10' });` should result in url `/api/posts/1/comments?from=2014-01-01&to=2014-01-10`