# Query params in async hasMany via link

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

With Ember Data you can do this:

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
   comments: DS.hasMany('comment', {async:true})
});
```

with the `links`-object you return from the server or serialize payload client-side like this:

```
{
  post:{
    id: 1,
    links: {
      comments: 'comments'
    }
  }
}
```

Ember Data generates the following url `/post/:post_id/comments` when you do `post.get('comments')`

But I got a lot of comments and I'd like to pass query params to it (just like a normal search in ember data): `post.get('comments',{ from: '2014-01-01', to: '2014-01-07' });`

Unfortunately it's not working. Is there another way?

See also my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20699095/dynamic-segment-in-ember-data-adapter/20709481)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a slew of ways to accomplish this, I'm gonna list them all out then maybe decide which seems the best,

#### Change the json returned from the server (Probably the most correct)

```
{
  post:{
    id: 1,
    links: {
      comments: 'comments?from=foo&to=bar'
    }
  }
}
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/155/edit

#### Modify the json in the serializer when you receive it

```
App.ColorSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  extractArray: function(store, type, payload) {
    console.log(payload);
    payload.colors.forEach(function(color){
      color.links.items += "?foo=bar";
    });
    return this._super(store, type, payload);     
  }
});
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/156/edit

#### Modify the request in the adapter to include extra info in certain cases

```
App.ColorAdapter= DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    findHasMany: function(store, record, url) {
    var host = Em.get(this, 'host'),
        id   = Em.get(record, 'id'),
        type = record.constructor.typeKey;

    if (host && url.charAt(0) === '/' && url.charAt(1) !== '/') {
      url = host + url;
    }
    // check if post comments
    var builtUrl = this.buildURL(type, id),
        withPrefix = this.urlPrefix(url, builtUrl),
        data = {from:'foo'};
      return this.ajax(withPrefix, 'GET',{data:data});
  },
});
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/154/edit

Comment: Thanks for the all the options, I realise that mapping Comments as `hasMany`-relationship is not the right way, because I need to query it on the server. I should search for another solution for my other question. I accept the answer because technically you did answer my question.

Comment: @Kingpin2k, I've asked the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27429174/filter-paginate-pass-parameters-to-asynchronous-ember-data-relationship-requests, the problem with this answer is you are giving example `foo=bar`, but I need to pass the parameter dynamically not just `bar` but for example with pagination: `foo=page1`, `foo=page2` and so on, can you answer my question please.

Answer (score 4):

I have written an addon to accomplish this: https://github.com/mdehoog/ember-data-has-many-query.

After installing and configuring, you should be able to query:

`post.query('comments', { from: '2014-01-01', to: '2014-01-07' });`

Answer (score 1):

I had to solve this problem. I couldn't find a clean solution and looking at Ember Data's source code I couldn't imagine something better. Perhaps this will help someone else.

---

Given a relationship like this and the need to pass query params to tell the API what comments need to be returned (e.g. you need to include a 'search' param or 'pageNumber' / 'pageSize' for pagination).

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  comments: DS.hasMany('comment', {async:true})
});
```

---

I added a key 'params' to the options object of the hasMany attribute. The value tells the adapter what other model attribute contains params related to that hasMany relationship. (Note that 'object' isn't a default EmberData attribute type see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/pixelhandler/10510984) to add that type.)

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  comments: DS.hasMany('comment', {async:true, params: 'comment_params'}),
  comment_params: DS.attr('object'),
});
```

With the model modified to provide query params we need our adapter to consume the information:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  findHasMany: function(store, snapshot, url, relationship) {
    var id   = snapshot.id;
    var type = snapshot.typeKey;

    url = this.urlPrefix(url, this.buildURL(type, id));

    if ('params' in relationship.options) {
      var params = snapshot.attr(relationship.options.params);
      if (params && Em.keys(params).length) {
        var queryParams = [];
        _.forEach(params, function (value, key) {
          queryParams.push(
            '%@=%@'.fmt(encodeURIComponent(key), encodeURIComponent(value))
          );
        });
        url = url + '?' + queryParams.join('&');
      }
    }

    return this.ajax(url, 'GET');
  },
});
```

Now you can use actions in routes/controllers or observers in your controllers to modify the params attribute, then call get() or reload() on your hasMany attribute:

```
  // some controller ...
  // assume a template with binding to 'query'
  queryDidChange: function() {
    var model = this.get('model');
    var params = model.getWithDefault('comment_params', {});

    var value = this.get('query').trim();
    if (value !== '') {
      params['search'] = value;
    } else {
      delete params['search'];
    }
    model.set('comment_params', params);
    // calling reload to get a new set of comments
    // if comments have not been loaded yet only the 'get' is
    // necessary.
    model.get('comments').reload();
  }.observes('query'),
```

---

Editorial:
I really wish I didn't need to add all this code, but it seems that returning all records for a hasMany is the default with no out of the box way to alter that.

---

Edit #2: I use '_.forEach' from lodash.  You could also use

```
Object.keys(params).forEach($same_foreach_function_as_above)
```