# filter paginate pass parameters to asynchronous ember data relationship requests

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rest, ember.js, ember-data

I want to implement paging/filtering on ember data asynchronously.

This is my `author` model:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  user: DS.belongsTo('user'),
  articles: DS.hasMany('article', { async: true }),
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  email: DS.attr('string')
});
```

route:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('author', params.author_id);
  }
});
```

controller:

```
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  popularArticles: function() {
    return this.get('model.articles').filter({ tab: 'popular' });
  }.property('model.articles')
});
```

Note that model has an `articles` property with `DS.hasMany('article', { async: true})` relationship.

If I use this property this request is made `authors/1/articles` and its asynchronous.

This is fine until I need to make request like `authors/1/articles?page=2` or `authors/1/articles?tab="hot"`.

One possible approach is, as shown in the controller, I have a `popularArticles` property that filters the `model.articles` property, and will make the filtered request without loading all the articles.

How can I pass query parameters to asynchronously loaded relationships in ember data?

Comment: Have you looked at [ember-cli-pagination](https://github.com/mharris717/ember-cli-pagination)?

Comment: @SamSelikoff, yes, but it doesn't support paginating hasMany relationships, besides I want to pass any query parameter, eg. filtering, not just for paging.

Answer (score 2):

This addon may help: https://github.com/mdehoog/ember-data-has-many-query.

Allows you to add query params to `has-many` relationships, eg:

`post.query('comments', { page: 1 });`

Answer (score 0):

In the controller you can do something like this:

```
import Ember from "ember";
import pagedArray from 'ember-cli-pagination/computed/paged-array';

export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  sortProperties: ['date'],
  sortAscending: false,

  page: 1,
  perPage: 5,

  pagedContent: pagedArray("arrangedContent", {pageBinding: "page", perPageBinding: "perPage"}),

  queryParams: ["page", "perPage"],

  totalPagesBinding: "pagedContent.totalPages"
});
```

Comment: I am already using `ember-cli-pagination` but I can't make it for `has-many` relationships. This code paginates the main model so for example `this.findPaged('todos')` will paginate todos. What I need is `this.findPaged('todo.comments')` where comments is a `hasMany` and loaded async. What I am asking is how to pass query params to a `hasMany` relationship query.

Comment: can `ember-cli-pagination` make queries like `posts/1/comments?page=3`.

Comment: I think it should also work on the comments controller. If I find the time I will try it.

Comment: can anyone give example of expected response?

Answer (score 0):

@peter-t I don know what example you search for but you can filter in a component like this:

`ember-cli-blog/app/components/blog-posts.js`

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import pagedArray from 'ember-cli-pagination/computed/paged-array';
import computedFilterByQuery from 'ember-cli-filter-by-query/util/filter';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

  pagedContent: pagedArray("filteredContent", {pageBinding: "page", perPageBinding: "perPage"}),

  totalPagesBinding: "pagedContent.totalPages",

  arrangedContent: function() {
    return Ember.ArrayProxy.extend(Ember.SortableMixin).create({
      sortProperties: ['date'],
      sortAscending: false,
      content: this.get('posts')
    });
  }.property('posts'),

  filteredContent: function() {
    return computedFilterByQuery(
      this.get('arrangedContent'),
      ['title', 'body', 'author', 'excerpt'],
      this.get('query'),
      { conjunction: 'and', sort: false}
    );
  }.property('arrangedContent.@each.title', 'arrangedContent.@each.author', 'query'),

  actions: {
    createPost: function() {
      this.sendAction('createAction');
    }
  }
});
```

`ember-cli-blog/app/templates/posts.hbs`

```
{{#blog-posts posts=model page=page perPage=perPage query=query createAction="createPost"}}{{outlet}}{{/blog-posts}}
```