# hasMany relationship with JSON links

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, json-api

I'm attempting to construct a dynamic REST call in my ember app. I was attempting to use this solution as a starting point but it's not working and I'm not sure if it's because Ember is now using JSON API and I'm structuring it wrong:
[Dynamic segment in ember data adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20699095/dynamic-segment-in-ember-data-adapter)

In the back end the call looks like `/posts/{postID}/comments` and I want to be able to dynamically get comments from post of ID 1, 2, 3, etc...
Here is my basic structure 
Post model:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  comments: DS.hasMany('comment', {async:true})
});
```

Comment Model:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Template:

```
<ul>
  {{#each model as |post|}}
    {{#each post.comments as |comment|}}
      <li>{{comment.name}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Json Post Payload:

```
  "data": [{
    "type": "posts",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
      "id": 1
      "name": "my title"
    },
    "links": {
      "comments": "comments"
    }
  }]
```

My goal is for the call to comments to construct a namespace that looks like `/posts/1/comments` using the template above. I'm getting the post model back and have verified that the first `{{#each}}` loop works, but the call to `post.comments` does nothing in the template.

Comment: It looks like you're missing the `belongsTo` https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/models/relationships/#toc_one-to-many

Comment: This didn't make a difference unfortunately

Comment: Is there an answer to this already?

Answer (score 2):

Your payload is not confirm the [JSON API](http://jsonapi.org/). Because `comments` is a relationship of `post`, the payload should look something like this:

```
"data": [{
  "type": "posts",
  "id": "1",
  "attributes": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "my title"
  },
  "relationships": {
    "comments": {
      "links": {
        "related": "/posts/1/comments"
      }
    }
  }
}]
```

Read [here](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-relationships) for more info regarding JSON API relationships.

---

**N.B.** The way your payload was build, does work with the old [RESTSerializer](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming you have access to change the payload response.  If not, you will have to work with a serializer to massage the data.

First, from what you have shown here, it doesn't look like you have loaded any of the comments into the model.

Your payload should probably look something like this:

```
"data": [{
  "type": "posts",
  "id": "1",
  "attributes": {
    "id": 1
    "name": "my title"
  },
  "relationships": {
    "comments": {
      "data": [
        {
          "id": "3",
          "name": "comment"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}]
```

Comment: This works but does not accomplish what I'm trying to do. Accessing this data will end up making a call to the back end for each comment id in the data array. I'm looking for one call to get all my comments. Instead of `/post/1/comments/1` I want `/post/1/comments`, which, from my understanding, should be working using the links attribute